# I've trying to use tokenizer to set name and surname

Tags: java

public static Player newPlayer(Integer playerNum){
            Player player = new Player();

```
        System.out.println("Player " + (playerNum+1) + " registration");

        try {
            String fullname = null;
            StringTokenizer lineTokens = new StringTokenizer(fullname);
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            String name = input.readLine();
            String surname = input.readLine();
            fullname = input.readLine();
            player.setName(name + surname);


            while (lineTokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                if ( lineTokens.countTokens() >= 0 ) {
                    name = lineTokens.nextToken();
                    surname = lineTokens.nextToken();
                    fullname = (name+" "+surname);
                } else {
                    String checkSpace = lineTokens.nextToken();
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkSpace.length(); i++) {
                        if ( checkSpace.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e){}
```

}

I need to set a name and a surname using Tokenizer it is crashing.
P.S I want learn how to use it instead of the split

Comment: You can’t initialize it with null, read the documentation! Also from the documentation, “StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons ...” so why learn it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you wanted to do, below is a short script to read first and last name from the user, using StringTokenizer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter name: <firstName> <lastName>");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, " ");
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    if (tokenizer.countTokens() >= 2){
        firstName = tokenizer.nextToken();
        lastName = tokenizer.nextToken();
    }
    System.out.println("first name is " + firstName);
    System.out.println("last name is " + lastName);
}
```